# JQM and CSS overrides

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using a nav element to create a menu. I am also using JQM to format a listview. The CSS of the JQM overrides the nav style and I simply cannot understand why.

This is my nav element with link elements:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="new.html">New</a></li>
        <li><a href="update.html">Update</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And this is the CSS for the link elements inside the nav element:

```
nav > ul > li > a {
    color: #aaa;
    background-color:#333;
    display: block;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The color attribute is overridden by the JQM stylesheet (turning out blue). The specific overriding setting has been identified as:

*.ui-page-theme-a a:visited, html .ui-bar-a a:visited, html .ui-body-a a:visited, html body .ui-group-theme-a a:visited {
    color: #38c;
}*

What I don't understand is why is it being overridden? The JQM style has some specific classes which I didn't specify in my nav element, so why am I losing the color settings? Why is the JQM style applied to my non-classed link/nav?

NB: I am complete noob when it comes to these things, so excuse my plain ignorance

Comment: As far as I can see it only says something about the :visited state, which you have not declared in your own css.

Answer (score 0):

The JQM styles are probably added by it's script. As soon as you initiate the element, it gets the classes assigned to it.

The reason that it overrules is because the selector is more specific. If you want to read more about specificity, follow [this link](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

If you want to overrule the JQM style, you have a few options

## Quick and dirty

Use the `!important` rule, it overrules all other styles

```
nav > ul > li > a {
    color: #aaa !important;
    background-color:#333;
    display: block;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

## Latter rule

Use the same selector, but be sure that **your stylesheet** is loaded **after** the JQM stylesheet

```
.ui-page-theme-a a:visited, 
html .ui-bar-a a:visited, 
html .ui-body-a a:visited, 
html body .ui-group-theme-a a:visited {
    color: #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Even before specificity, why does the JQM rule apply to the 'a' in my nav element? 
If I understand CSS right, then the rule for the 'a' in the JQM style should only apply if the 'a' element is under one of the classes .ui-page-theme-a | .ui-bar-a | .ui-body-a | .ui-group-theme-a, and the 'a' in my nav element is not part of any of those classes?

Comment: jQuery can add classes to elements, also after page load, or on click, hover, etc. If you use Firefox, right click on a element > "Inspect element". You then can see what classes the element has.

Comment: Thanks! I have just noticed this myself after re-reading your first reply. It added classes to my 'a' element, and also added a div element with classes to the entire page. Outrages!